# UITableView in UIVIew freezes on reload while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I have a UIViewController that has a UITableView in it. I wanted to have a Search bar which displays text and has Button that pulls up a UIPickerView with options. when I select any option from the UIPickerView the tableView reloads. There are two problems that I have noticed so far:

1. Each cell of my tableView covers approx. 400px in height; when I scroll the tableView and leave it in a position where the cell is halfway/little more than halfway out, and I reload the table with 0 rows the entire app freezes, and the XCode does not record any error
2. When I pull up the Picker and make a selection while making the tableview in the background scroll, the app freezes again, which not recording any error

In either case, the app does not crash(does not quit), but freezes the UI making any other interaction impossible. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

Following is the code:
- Code for custom Search bar 
`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    _leftMonthButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(leftArrowX, 0, leftArrowWidth, 40)];
    _leftMonthButton.imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [_leftMonthButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-left.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_leftMonthButton addTarget:self action:@selector(monthSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    _rightMonthButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rightArrowX, 0, rightArrowWidth, 40)];
    _rightMonthButton.imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [_rightMonthButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_rightMonthButton addTarget:self action:@selector(monthSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    _dropDownButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _dropDownButton.frame=CGRectMake(downArrowX, 0, downArrowWidth, 40);
    _dropDownButton.imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [_dropDownButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_dropDownButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dropDownButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    _activeMonthIndex=1;

    [self addSubview:_leftMonthButton];
    [self addSubview:_rightMonthButton];
    [self addSubview:_dropDownButton];

    CGRect frame=_dropDownButton.frame;
    frame=CGRectMake(downArrowX, 0, downArrowWidth, 40);
    _dropDownButton.frame=frame;
}


(void)dropDownButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{

    [self.searchBarDelegate brandPickerClicked];
}

(void)monthSwitched:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (sender==_leftMonthButton)
    {
        if (_activeMonthIndex>0)
        {
            if (_rightMonthButton.alpha==0) _rightMonthButton.alpha=1;
            _activeMonthIndex-=1;
            _monthLabel.text=_activeMonths[_activeMonthIndex];
        }
        if (_activeMonthIndex==0)
        {
            _leftMonthButton.alpha=0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (_activeMonthIndex<2)
        {
            if (_leftMonthButton.alpha==0) _leftMonthButton.alpha=1;
            _activeMonthIndex+=1;
            _monthLabel.text=_activeMonths[_activeMonthIndex];
        }
        if (_activeMonthIndex==2)
        {
            _rightMonthButton.alpha=0;
        }
    }
    [self.searchBarDelegate monthChangedTo:_monthLabel.text];
}`
```

-Code for tableView implementing the searchBar

`
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

```
    _searchBar=[[CalendarSearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 40)];
    _searchBar.searchBarDelegate=self;
    [_headerView addSubview:_searchBar];

    self.calendarTable.dataSource=self;
    self.calendarTable.delegate=self;
    self.calendarTable.allowsSelection=false;

    UIView *tableViewFooter=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 23)];
    tableViewFooter.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorwithHexString:@"333333" alpha:1];

    [self.calendarTable setTableFooterView:tableViewFooter];

    _calendar=[CalendarData sharedReleaseData];
    _currentTableRowItems=_calendar;

    CGFloat screenHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat screenWidth=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    _picker=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-400, screenWidth, 400.0)];
    _picker.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorwithHexString:@"666666" alpha:1];
    _picker.dataSource=self;
    _picker.delegate=self;
}

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return _currentTableRowItems.count;
    }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    calendarCell *cell = (CalendarCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"calendarCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CalendarObject *object=_currentTableRowItems[indexPath.row];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorwithHexString:@"333333" alpha:1];
    cell.calendarCardView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height*479/568;
}

// Picker Controller Delegate Methods
-(void)pickerClicked
{
    if (![_picker isDescendantOfView:self.view])
    {
        [self.calendarTable setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
        [self.calendarTable setScrollEnabled:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:_picker];
    }
}

-(void)updateTableViewObjectsWithSearchString:(NSString*)searchString andSearchContext:(SearchContext)searchContext
{
    [_currentTableRowItems removeAllObjects];

    if (searchContext==date)
    {
            for (CalendarObject *object in _calendar.calendarArray)
            {
                if ([object.date.text compare:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]==NSOrderedSame && [object.monthName compare:_searchBar.monthLabel.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]==NSOrderedSame) [_currentTableRowItems addObject:object];
            }
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.releaseCalendarTable reloadData];
    });

   // [self.calendarTable setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}

//Data Source Picker View
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _searchBar.dates.count;
}

- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *title = _searchBar.dateArray[row];
    NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{
                                                                                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                                                                  NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"UnitedSansRegTT-Bold" size:18.0f],
                                                                                                  }];
    return attString;
}

//PickerView Delegate
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [self.calendarTable setScrollEnabled:YES];
    _searchBar.label.text=_searchBar.brandNames[row];
    [self updateTableViewObjectsWithSearchString:_searchBar.label.text andSearchContext:date];
    [self.picker removeFromSuperview];
}
```

`

Comment: Post your entire code so we can see where the problem is

Comment: I have added the code to it, please let me know if you need any explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think i got your issue you are adding subviews on drawrect.Don't do that draw rect is only for drawing the specific view.This is a very bad practice move it in initwithframe or if a nib is attached do it in awakefromnib and don't add and remove pickerview, create a view inside it will be pickerview and hide/show it

Comment: You want me to create a seperate view for the pickerView so that it stays in the memory?

Comment: You have to understand that creating and destroying ui is expensive as to hiding and showing them and the view will take more memory when its visible other it won't take much.